# How to create objects for pointer members

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

```
class A{
private:
    Fifi * fifi;
public setFifi(Fifi * aFifi){
    fifi = aFifi;
}
};

int main(){
    Fifi f;
    A a;
    a.setFifi(f);
}
```

Although it's not implemented in the code above, `class A` is actually a singleton. What I want to know is if i'll still be able to acces the `fifi` member one the main-scope is finished. (Assuming A is a singleton)

Or will the `f` object be lost and should I create it with the `new` keyword to still be able to access it?

Comment: The code doesn't even compile. Search for a million duplicates on "vexing parse" on this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `Fifi f();` is a function declaration

I assume you meant:

```
Fifi f;
```

In that case `f` will be destroyed when `main` is finished

I suggest you to use `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` to construct `Fifi` on the heap and store it in `A` (as `shared_ptr`)

Comment: @Sled: `new` is almost never correct (or at least "appropriate", but at your level think "correct") in C++.

Comment: @Sled: it will, but you will have not to forget and call `delete` later. Using `smart_pointer` is much safer solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Fifi f();
A a();
```

These statements do not do what I think you expect them to do. In short, they will not define variables.

`class A` doesn't look like a singleton to me. In it's current state, it's state will not be preserved after main finishes (although I'm not sure how you expect to access it after `main` finishes).

Comment: Yea sorry I have a few typos. And A doesn't implement singleton, I said assuming. The point is that I am able to call the `a` variable later in the code and I `f` to still be there once the main() scope is over.